# Demodulation of IQ signals from SDRs

Tags: python, sdr

I am writing a Python program for an SDR in which I need to process the signal that the SDR will receive. My problem is that the SDR provides an array of complex values, which is tantamount to using IQ modulation. However, in order to process the received sample, apply filters, decode etc., I need to convert this array into an array of real numbers in the time domain.

I have tried a number of diagrams from the web that illustrate IQ demodulation but cannot get the array correct. Does anyone have an example or can direct how to perform such a conversion?

Comment: no, you don't need to convert this to an array of real numbers. Most SDR processing happens on exactly that complex baseband you're using. So, what brings you to the conclusion that you must somehow convert this to real values?

Comment: Suppose the signal received by the SDR is two DTMF signals on two different bands, but close to each other. I would like to know the frequency characteristics of this sample, further I would like to isolate one DTMF signal by filtering the samples. I have the knowledge of how to do this, but for the real signal. Is it possible to process the samples in complex form in the same way? I do not see how AM, FM or PPM can be decoded on complex samples. I apologise if I am in the wrong.

Comment: yep, exactly the same mechanism work, but typically in an easier manner. I'd do DTMF decoding with a filterbank of 8 bandpasses in complex baseband, or the Goertzel algorithm; and Goertzel is actually *defined* for complex signals, the fact that it works for real signals is just a "special case".

Comment: This is amazing! Especially since all the signal processing material talks about real signal processing not a word about the complex form. I'll have to get used to using complex numbers. Thank you for the direction!

Comment: I think https://pysdr.org is a good resource